# How to call `catch` closure for every failed job in job batches Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, queue, jobs, batching

Laravel 8 introduced Job Batching, which allows to execute jobs in batches and perform actions on batch completion and failure. When a job within batch fails, the `catch` callback is executed and the whole batch is marked as "canceled" [according to the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues#batch-failures). In case you don't want the batch to cancel (on the first failure) you can append the method `allowFailures()` while dispatching the batch:

```
$batch = Bus::batch([
    // ...
])->then(function (Batch $batch) {
    // All jobs completed successfully...
})->catch(function (Batch $batch, Throwable $e) {
    // First batch job failure detected...
    
    // TODO: call this for every failed job

})->allowFailures()->dispatch();
```

It works as expected, however I wonder whether it's possible to call `catch` closure for every failed job? (at this case with `allowFailures`)

Answer (score 0):

You can use number of attemtps in Jobs for finding failed job

```
  if ($this->attempts() > 1) {
  // your code
  }
```